# How to import "describe" and "it" from mocha in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, mocha.js

By default, when importing `mocha` in TypeScript, it brings in `describe` and `it` (and some others) into the global namespace.

Is there a way to bring in specific imports like `import {describe, it} from 'mocha'`?

Comment: Why do you import them in the first place ? When you run `mocha` they are available globally. All that is required is to have the typings available

Comment: Only because I want to avoid globals in the first place. I realise mocha default behaviour is to put them in the global namespace, but I was hoping they had a way to explicitly import them.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Install mocha and its types:

```sh
npm install mocha --save-dev
npm install @types/mocha --save-dev
```

Then, simply import mocha in your test files:

```js
import 'mocha';

describe('my test', () => {
  it('does something', () => {
    // your test
  });
});
```

Comment: In fact, only installing @types/mocha works out of the box. :)

Answer (score 28):

Since TypeScript 2.0, you can add `mocha` to the `types` configuration of your `tsconfig.json` and it will always be loaded:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
      "mocha"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This works because the [@types/mocha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mocha) package exists, doesn't it?

Answer (score -1):

I was having issues with errors and warnings, the problem stemmed from me renaming `tsconfig.json` to something else which makes Visual Studio Code enter "File Scope" instead of "Explicit Project". That made it impossible to import `it` without a red squiggly. Now that I've renamed the config back to `tsconfig.json` then `import 'mocha';` works as Eryk mentioned.

https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/typescript