# How to use chakramjs for a typescript project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mocha.js, typescript2.0

I am writing a node application in typescript, and am pretty inexperienced with both nodejs and typescript.

I want to use [chakram](http://dareid.github.io/chakram/) to test the API endpoints, yet [chakram lacks typescript definiton](https://github.com/dareid/chakram/issues/33).

The more general question is [how to import a library without definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842389/how-to-import-a-js-library-without-definition-file-in-typescript-file), yet the way I am supposed to to apply the answers still eludes me. The provided answer are too abstract for my current understanding, so I would like a more concrete example.

Basically, I don't know how to transform the working javascript `healthcheck.js`:

```
var chakram = require('chakram'),
    expect = chakram.expect;

describe("Rest API Healthceck", function () {
    it('should respond with HTTP STATUS OK NO CONTENT', function () {
        var response = chakram.get("http://app.local/api/status", {});
        expect(response).to.have.status(204);

        return chakram.wait();
    });
});
```

into its typescript variant.

I tried to work with `any`, as I don't want to provide my own typings *yet*, I just want it to work.

I tried im my `healthcheck.ts` file with:

```
let it: any;
let describe: any;
let chakram: any;
chakram = require('chakram');
const expect = chakram.expect;

describe("Rest API Healthceck", function () {
    it('should respond with HTTP STATUS OK NO CONTENT', function () {
        var response = chakram.get("http://app.local/api/status", {});
        expect(response).to.have.status(204);

        return chakram.wait();
    });
});
```

It does compile yet it throws an error if I try to execute the test with mocha by `./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha dist/tests/acceptance/healthcheck.js`, namely:

```
TypeError: describe is not a function
```

Investigating the error further I am also not sure if the issue has to do with [mocha and how its types are loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39816482/how-to-import-describe-and-it-from-mocha-in-typescript). I am also using typings and not definilty typed, that may also be another problem.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To make the test run I had to make typings aware of mocha:

```
./node_modules/typings/dist/bin.js install env~mocha --global
```

The problem was due to missing defintion of mocha and unrelated to chakramjs.

In order for it to run then, my typescript testcase looks like:

```
let chakram: any;
chakram = require('chakram');
const expect = chakram.expect;

describe("Rest API Healthceck", function () {
    it('should respond with HTTP STATUS OK NO CONTENT', function () {
        var response = chakram.get("http://app.local/api/status", {});
        expect(response).to.have.status(204);

        return chakram.wait();
    });
});
```