# Disabling linting errors when writing test files?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js, chai, eslint

[image: capture]

Those errors are pretty useless and annoying when it comes to writing test files.  "Cannot find name 'describe.'". How would I go about disabling these errors? I tried writing `/* eslint-disable */` at the top and it didn't work. I tried the same thing but replacing the eslint with tslint since im using typescript and it still doesn't work.

I create a .eslintignore file in the directory and it still doesn't make those fake-errors disappear. 
What is the solution? Thank you

Comment: What editor is this?

Comment: @lumio it looks like atom.

Comment: I thought the same. But just to be sure :)

Comment: Rather than disabling configure TypeScript in its tsconfig to properly includes the types. Did you install @types/mocha and @types/chai?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39816482/457268

Comment: make sure after adding the path to your test file to .eslintignore that you resave that test file. In some cases this triggers eslint which should no longer be called for that specified test file

Comment: add this to the top of the file `// tslint:disable`