# TypeScript Mocha: Module '"mocha"' has no exported member 'describe'. (2305)

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, webstorm

```
import {describe, it} from 'mocha'
import {expect} from "chai"

describe('Example Mocha Test 1', function () {
    it('Should test foo', function () {
        let foo = 'bar'
        expect(foo, 'because foo is str').to.be.a('string')
    })
})
```

Getting the errors:

```
Module '"mocha"' has no exported member 'describe'. (2305)
Module '"mocha"' has no exported member 'it'. (2305)
```

This way of importing worked yesterday so I changed my whole project to this format and today suddenly it decided not to work.

The reason I want to import `describe` and `it` is because the IDE (WebStorm) starts autocompleting when I import it like this.

When I change the code to:

```
import 'mocha'
```

The code compiles and tests start to run again. But I don't get the autocomplete.

I have `"@types/mocha": "2.2.44",` installed.

What should I do?

Comment: This kind of worked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39816482/how-to-import-describe-and-it-from-mocha-in-typescript

Answer (score 0):

`@types/mocha/index.d.ts` v. 2.2.44 doesn't include any named exports for `describe`, etc., so compiler errors are expected. `import * as mocha from 'mocha';` works, but is not actually required - you don't need importing `describe`, etc. explicitly, as mocha adds them to global namespace